# How to access the time of an event of Google Calendar?

Tags: python

I am using Google Calendar APIs and Google Client Library for Python. The code that I use gives the list of the events that falls in a given date range but the time is missing. I want an output that gives the list of the events as well as the time. Here is the code:

```
page_token = None

while True:

    events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary',pageToken=page_token,
        timeMin='2014-06-03T00:00:00+05:30',
        timeMax='2014-06-05T00:00:00+05:30').execute()

    print 'Daterange for events in primary calendar:2014-06-03 and 2014-06-05'

    for event in events['items']:
        print event['summary']
    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```

on adding print event['start'] and print event['end'] , i do get the output in the following format

```
             Start time: {u'dateTime': u'2014-06-03T09:00:00-04:00'}
             End time: {u'dateTime': u'2014-06-03T10:00:00-04:00'}
```

i want it to be like:

```
             Start time: DATE:23/05/2014 TIME: 01:00PM
         End time:   DATE:23/05/2014 TIME: 02:00PM
```

please suggest a method.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you shouldn't access `event['summary']`, but `event['start.datetime']`.

See the [**docs**](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) for Event.